# Error in erlang when using records

Tags: erlang, record

I have created a simple program that should simulate an address book:

```
%% API
-export([]).
-export([createAddressBook/0]).
-export([checkIfExist/3]).
-export([addContact/3]).
-record(entry,{nameAndSurname,n_phone,email}).

createAddressBook() ->
  Test = #entry{nameAndSurname = {"Marcin", "Majewski"}, n_phone = [997], email=["call@call.tv"]},
  [Test].

checkIfExist(_,_,[]) -> false;
checkIfExist(Name,Surname,[H|L]) ->
  if
    H#entry.nameAndSurname == {Name,Surname} -> true;
    true -> checkIfExist(Name,Surname,L)
  end.

addContact(Name,Surname,L)->
  case checkIfExist(Name,Surname,L) of
    true -> io:format("Entry already exist, nothing was created!");
    _ -> newEntry = #entry{nameAndSurname = {Name,Surname}, n_phone = [],email = []},lists:append(L,newEntry)
  end.
```

But when I invoke:

```
X=module_name:createAddressBook().
B=module_name:addContact("Name","Surname",X).
```

I am getting an error:

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 
{entry,{"Name","Surname"},[],[]}
in function addContact
```

I do not understand what causes this problem.

Comment: You forgot to define surname in the function and it has no default value in the record definition. You might want to bring questions like this to the mailing list or forum, not SO.

Comment: @zxq9 That is right I forgot but it does not solve the problem. Why shouldn't I bring this question to SO?

Comment: Something amounting to a typo or simple mistake in code usually doesn't do well here -- actually, things like this rarely generate answers (notice I commented, not answered) and eventually get deleted. Sometimes stuff like this gets completely ignored. OTOH, bringing something like this to IRC, the list, or forum is almost guaranteed to both get an answer and a bit more sympathy than you might find here.

Comment: @zxq9 Do you know some good erlang forum where this kind of basic question gets answers (and a forum with huge number of members)?

Comment: "Huge number of members"? Nothing like Java/PHP/Ruby/[or any other version of that language family]. Sometimes it seems like the entire Erlang community can fit on a single city bus... erlangcentral.org is tiny, but its the most common forum. The best place to get help is IRC or the ML. If you are in Europe IRC is nearly always live during the day, decent activity daytime in the US, but a bit harder if you're in Asia (like me).

Comment: Yes, your real problem was trying to assign to an atom, as VK noted below. One of the reasons you had that problem is your typographical convention! Use CamelCase (*starting* with an upper case character) for *variable* names, use underscore_linked_names for atoms and function names. This makes Erlang code *much* more readable, even without syntax highlighting. If you always do this, you will not have this problem -- what is an atom and what is a variable will always be distinct to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are tryin to assign record to atom:

```
newEntry = #entry{nameAndSurname = {Name,Surname}, n_phone = [],email = []},lists:append(L,newEntry)
```

Since `newEntry` starts from lowercase letter, erlang treats it as atom, but not variable. Just change it:

```
NewEntry = #entry{nameAndSurname = {Name,Surname}, n_phone = [],email]},
lists:append(L,NewEntry)
```

Comment: Ans yes, I completely agree with @zxq9, this question is quite far from SO-format.

Comment: Don't forget that when someone ask a question, he has not the answer, and thus he can't know if it is a typo or something else. To @Marcin, I suggest that you look closer at the error message, it says almost all you need to know to solve your issue: error type, code line, right hand side value... If I can give you an advice, don't put multiple expression on a single line, it is easier to read, and you get more information when debugging.

Comment: @Pascal, your remark about *nature of question* is reasonable, but I believe that same question should be formulated another way to be more usefull for people, who may encountered simllar ussue (but not exactly the same).